# Role design pattern in uml

Tags: object-oriented-design, uml, class-diagram

In my UML class diagram, I have an interface called `Contract` which a `Staff` implements. There are two types of `Staffs`: one is `partTime` and the other is `fullTime`.

Does that mean that the two `partTime` and `fullTime` classes inherit from `Staff` class?  More generally, can you inherit an implemented class?

Comment: "can you inherit an implemented class?" Sure so long as it isn't sealed or final (keyword term depends on language). But it is not ideal as it can lead to multiple implementing layers which causes [the yo-yo problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yo-yo_problem).

Answer (score 6):

**Can a class inherited an implementation of interface ?**

The [interface realization](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/realization.html) expresses that a class `X` implements a an interface `I`.  Class `X` can then, like any other class be specialized further by letting other classes [inherit](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/generalization.html) from it.

**Your UML diagram**

You could therefore have an interface `Contract`, and have several implementation such as `Freelancer` or `Staff`.  And of course `Staff` could have two specialization `FullTime` and `PartTime` as you envisage:

[image]

However, part time could need further specialization, such as half-time, one-day-a-week, two-days-a-week, etc...  The question is:  **is-a** `Staff` a `FullTime` or a `Partime` ?  Or **has a** staff a `FullTime` or a `PartTime` schedule or work-time ?  Furthermore, wouldn't a freelancer have a similar specialization ? That could make the class model very dense and rigid.

The rule of the thumb says

> [Prefer composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

So if you're not 100% sure that inheritance is really required, prefer to use composition instead, so that you'd have an association between a `Staff` and `WorkSchedule`.

[image]

The class `WorkSchedule` could define the properties that characterizes the work schedule in a flexible manner. Of course, it could be specialized further if deemed useful.